# Great Ruby on Rails resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm generally a PHP dev, but over the past few months I have been dying to get into a new language. I have tried everything, I learned a little Java, not for me; a little Python, I dislike the syntax, I wanted to try Perl, but never got around to it. On the other hand I started to read an ebook on Ruby, and I really like the language, I'v decided that when all is said and done that I want to develop in not only PHP, but Ruby as well. The issue was that I only code for the web, and not computer application based programs. I have searched for hours on Google just trying to find a resource(s) that would allow me to run a normal ruby .rb script within my browser with no strings attached. All I seemed to get was a web IRB applet.

I was highly against the idea of using a framework, as I despise most of them, except the Javascript ones. However after some time, I got over the crap and tried out Ruby on rails (ROR). To be honest the only reason I like it is that it allows me to run the application in my browser, and I'm able to create a UI. Other then that it does nothing for me.

To finally ask my question, I would greatly appreciate anyone that can point me to great ROR' resources, not books but online tutorials, that don't have to do with Scaffolding (err)... Right now I use the net.tutplus sites for a resource and I love that type of content especially this tutorial: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/from-codeigniter-to-ruby-on-rails-a-conversion/

I do pay every 3 months for a subscription to that site, for their super top quality tutorials, so I don't mind spending a little cash. Although, free in this case is always better.

Anyway sorry for making you reading so much, I suppose I can't control my fingers... (That was a joke, hah ;)) Any answer you have to offer would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

The first place for all budding ruby/rails programmers should be Ryan Bates [Railcasts](http://railscasts.com/) these are short screencasts discussing many aspects of rails.

Answer (score 1):

The [official Ruby on Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org) are a great way to get started with Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 0):

Great Books include: [Beginning Ruby](http://books.google.com/books?id=A78bYfzYKZ4C&dq=beginning+ruby+from+novice+to+pro&source=gbs_navlinks_s) from Novice to Professional by Peter Cooper. From there move on to [Agile Web Development with Rails](http://books.google.com/books?id=V5pPPgAACAAJ&dq=agile+web+dev&ei=epokS7LgFqmQyATGxbS1Ag&cd=3) by Sam Ruby, Dave Thomas and David Heinemeier Hansson.

Great podcasts include [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/), [Railslab: Scaling Rails](http://railslab.newrelic.com/scaling-rails) and [Learning Rails](http://www.buildingwebapps.com/podcasts).

Of Course, the best place I've found for my odd rails related questions has been the [stackoverflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com) community. For every single question I've asked I've found very interesting answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you can manage your way around. [Ruby-Doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/) &
[Rails Doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/)

Answer (score 0):

While you said no books, I would still recommend Learn Ruby the Hard Way. You can get it as a PDF or in book form. It's not a sit down read it's a book of exercises and I think it's the best beginner book I've found. It is for ruby so no scaffolding and will give you instructions on how to run the exercises on your computer.

For online tutorials,
Ruby on Rails Guides https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html
Geeks for Geeks Ruby https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ruby-programming-language/?ref=header_search

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is a very old question and, back when it was posted, it may have been acceptable. However, we now generally close questions that are asking for recommendations for books, tutorials and other off-site resources, rather than answer them.